# An Access Form:How to get PDF of a access form

Tags: ms-access, pdf

I have a Icon of PDF in my form that I have created in Access 2010. There are 3 tabs in that form; each tab have a separate form page and PDF icon is common for all the tabs.

Now I want that whenever a user click on that icon a PDF file of that form get created.

**I have written this code**

```
Private Sub cmdPrintReportPDF_Click()

    Dim strDefaultPrinter As String
    strDefaultPrinter = Application.Printer.DeviceName

    **Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers("PDFCreator")**
    'DoCmd.PrintOut acPrintAll

    DoCmd.OpenReport "Graph_report", acViewNormal

    Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers(strDefaultPrinter)
End Sub
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid procedure call or argument on line no 4.
Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers("PDFCreator")
```

Comment: I believe what he is getting at is that when a command button is selected, he wants the form to be auto-printed to PDF format...  though I would suggest he do this with a report instead.

Comment: yes i want that on click of button ,it converted my current form into pdf format

Answer (score 2):

I have PDFCreator installed and this line, which triggers an error for you, does not trigger an error for me.

```
Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers("PDFCreator")
```

Go to the Immediate Window of the VB Editor and see if you also get an error with this line:

```
? Application.Printers("PDFCreator").DeviceName
```

If that also triggers an error, you probably don't have a printer whose DeviceName is PDFCreator.  You can list the names of the printers with this procedure.

```
Public Sub ListPrinters()
    Dim objPrinter As Printer

    For Each objPrinter In Application.Printers
        Debug.Print objPrinter.DeviceName
    Next objPrinter
End Sub
```

However, with Access 2010, I think you can create a PDF without using your PDFCreator print device.  At least this works for me with Access 2007, so I'm guessing it will work for you.

```
Private Sub cmdSaveAsPdf3_Click()
    Dim strPath AS String
    strPath = CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92) & "Sample3.pdf"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "fsubSample3", acFormatPDF, strPath
End Sub
```

That button click code creates a PDF (Sample3.pdf) of the form (fsubSample3) embedded in a page of my main form's tab control ... which is what I thought you wanted based on the original version of your question.  Now it seems you're wanting to create a PDF of a report rather than a form.  You can adapt the DoCmd.OutputTo line to use a report instead of a form.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
  Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers("PDFCreator")
```

...to this:

```
  Application.Printer = Application.Printers("PDFCreator")
```

`Application.Printer` is a property, not an object, so it doesn't use SET to change it.